# ASP.NET site getting hacked - links appended to aspx files

Tags: asp.net

A friend is asking about their ASP.NET site that has been getting hacked.  It's on a hosted server - cheapo hosting.

I haven't seen it myself just yet, but I'm hoping for ideas on where to look once I do.

The symptoms reported are that links, some mangled, are appearing appended to the .ASPX file (aspx/html on the disk).

Before I learned this, I thought it was SQL injection with links getting appended to their poorly written (I've seen that one) "content manager" content.  So I don't think that SQL injection could do this.

Anyone else seen this kind of hack?

Comment: Could be lots of things -e.g. a vulnerability in the FTP program or compromised FTP password what do the hosts say?

Comment: Maybe, but if it were that broad, why wouldn't they just take the entire site over?

Comment: To the close-voter - this isn't just a "helpz site hackdd!!!" post.  I'm trying to narrow it down.  Also, I doubt this attack is targeted, so finding the symptoms and cause will help future searchers with the same vulnerability.

Comment: @uosɐſ: It's just like a virus; if it kills the host immediately, there is noone to spread it. They are trying to use the little spider cred that the page has to increase their cred. If they took over the site, the spiders would see that there was no content left, and ignore it.

Comment: @uosɐſ - I was the close voter. This does seem to fit server fault's remit better than SO's to me at least. Server admins are probably more likely to have had to resolve this type of attack before.

Comment: @Martin - I agree that it's on the border line.  Depending on the problem, it could be a server configuration or a SQL-injection-like attack that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why wouldn't they just take the entire site over?

Because then you'd notice. The usual aim is to add linkfarming and trojan-loading exploits to a popular site for as long as possible before the admin notices and takes it off-line.

If your actual .aspx files are being appended to, then that's probably a trivial automated attack on an FTP site using stolen passwords. Most commonly today, this happened because a client machine that has been used to connect to the FTP has been hacked and a password-stealing trojan installed.

Check all client machines that have been anywhere near the FTP *thoroughly* (and reinstall dirty systems completely rather than using today's unreliable anti-virus software to attempt to ‘clean’ them). Then change the password for FTP access (much better: use SFTP. FTP is an insecure pile of crud that no-one should be using in this century).